FirewallD Direct Rules
Should be a fairly straightforward one but I'm getting conflicting information from different places.
I understand that Direct Rules take precedence over FirewallD zones, but if the default policy for my Direct Rules chains (e.g. in FirewallBackend NFTables) is ACCEPT, are my FirewallD zones still going to be adhered to? For example, if I have SSH in my trusted zone with an IP address but I have a Direct Rule that ACCEPTs SSH traffic from anywhere, would my FirewallD zone be ignored and the SSH traffic just accepted straight away?
